# Using union and area increases?

Tags: layers, union

I have two layers … assume A and B … one is landuse and one is limit of that.

The main reason to union these two layers is to calculate street.

But my problem is after I union these two the area increase.

Logically it should not be more than the limit, because the landuse layer is in limit.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to **edit** your question to include the GIS software (and version) that you are using, please?

Comment: I did want to mention that my response is technically only true for layers with good topology that controls polygon overlaps.  Really bad polygon topology (overlaps and gaps) can cause weird effects on the area calculations.  Two layers with large amounts of internally overlapping polygons may result in an Intersect that creates more area than the shared area contained in the original layers due to the way the overlaps will be combined.

Comment: Dear Richard, I use ArcGis 10.1 moreover I checked topology and fixed the overlay errors, mostly the errors were for polygons.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, logically **Union** is the the area shared by both plus the area of each of the two layers not shared by the other.  Therefore the area returned must be **equal to or greater than** the area in the **largest layer**.  This is what you are seeing.

The way to extract just the portion where the land use layer and the limit layer intersect is to use the **Intersect** tool, which only returns the area shared by both layers.  The area returned by that tool can only be **equal to or less than** the area of the **smallest layer**.  That is sort of the tool you thought you were using.

The intersected portion of the Union tool can be found by using the layer FID fields added by that tool to the output.  So, for example, lets say it created fields named LANDUSE_FID and LIMIT_FID.  In that case the intersected portion of the Union contained by both layers is everywhere LANDUSE_FID > -1 AND LIMIT_FID > -1.  The portion only in the limit layer and not in the land use layer would be selected as LANDUSE_FID = -1 AND LIMIT_FID > -1.  If you wanted all portions of the limit layer regardless of whether or not it was in the Land Use layer, just select LIMIT_FID > -1.